Determine amplitude of fourier series?
Can a Fourier series be used to determine the amplitude of a periodic function?
I have a periodic function which happens to be the sum of a number of sawtooth functions.  The individual sawtooth components all have amplitude 1 but different periods.  When summed, the function has a period which is the lowest common multiple of the periods of the component sawtooth functions.
The amplitude of the period function depends on the frequency of the individual sawtooth components.  As I understand it, I can determine the trigonometric Fourier series for the summed function. But can this be used to determine the amplitude of the summed components?
